# Prism, Traversal, or Fold from readMaybe

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-lens

In working with lenses, I occasionally have the need for some basic text parsing in the chain of optics. In one API I'm dealing with, there is a JSON field like this:

```
"timespent": "0.25",
```

Since it is incorrectly encoded as a string instead of a number, I can't just do the typical `lens-aeson` solution:

```
v ^? key "timespent" . _Double -- this doesn't work
```

So, I need this instead:

```
v ^? key "timespent" . _String . mystery
```

where the `mystery` optic needs to turn `Text` into a `Double`. I know that `mystery` could be typed as follows:

```
mystery :: Prism' Text Double
```

And I could built this as follows:

```
mystery = prism' (pack . show) (readMaybe . unpack)
```

And technically, this function could have an even more general type signature with `Read` and `Show` constraints, but that's not really what my question is about. What I don't like is the `Prism` is really too strong for what I'm doing. Most of the time, I'm interested in parsing but not is rendering it back to a string. So, I need either a `Traversal` or a `Fold` but I'm not sure which one, and I'm not sure how to build them. When I look at the type signature of `^?` to find the minimum optic required, I see:

```
(^?) :: s -> Getting (First a) s a -> Maybe a
```

I can sort of understand what this means but not very well. So, to make my question clear, it is:

If I have a function `f :: Text -> Maybe a`, how can I turn this into a `Traversal` or a `Fold`? Thanks, and let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Comment: One option is to use a custom `parseJSON` so the string interpretation is integrated. The aeson parser type is *monadic*, so there's no difficulty producing a parse error from a higher stratum. Instead of thinking about `.`, consider `=<<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is a [Getter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Getter):

```
_Read :: Read a => Getter Text (Maybe a)
_Read f = contramap g . f . g where g = readMaybe . unpack
```

In general, if you have `x :: a -> b` then `\f -> contramap x . f . x` is a `Getter a b`.

Then to get the `a` value out of the `Maybe a`, use `traverse`, so combined you have `_Read . traverse` which is a `Read a => Fold Text a`.

Comment: close, but not quite. I would like it to be parameterized over `Text` and `a` (not `Maybe a`), so `Getter` doesn't seem to work. To be specific, if I used your `_Read` function as `mystery`, then the type of `v ^? key "timespent" . _String . mystery` (from my post) would be `Maybe (Maybe Double)`, but I would like it to be `Maybe Double`.

Comment: what about `_Read . traverse`?

Comment: I think that will work. What would the type of that be? Is it `Fold Text a`?

Comment: according to GHCi it's a `Read a => Fold Text a`.